# Matlab showing missing as git status, but files are being managed fine by git

Tags: git, matlab

I have been managing version control via the command line on my project, but turned on the git integration in matlab to make it nice and easy to see what files have been altered.

Yesterday I had a change of heart over my naming conventions and capitalised the name of some files which were then successfully added and committed with git via the command line.

Now I have a little red icon next to my changed files (only these ones) which says missing when I hover over. I can still access and alter the files and do everything one would normally be able to do, but I cannot get rid of the red icons.

[image]

I've tried turning git integration off and on again in git, moving my .git folder away and back to the folder and opening matlab in between.

I can't seem to find a way to delete the source control settings for the project and re-initiate source control in its current status as I expect that would help.

edit - this is on windows 10 using matlab 2021b

Comment: What OS are you using? Windows?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Windows 10

Comment: Does the commit that "added" the renamed files show adds only, or adds and deletes of the old names, or perhaps showing as a rename?

Comment: @CrisLuengo It seems to show them as adds (+ symbols next to each of the files) with no deletions or any files with - symbols. Running `git ls-tree -r main --name-only` confirms that the capitalised and non-capitalised versions are currently being tracked

Comment: So it's an issue of the case-insensitive file system. I would move the renamed files to a temp directory, remove both versions of the files from git in one commit, then move the files back, and add them anew to git. You do lose the ability to track changes for these files, but I don't see any way to avoid that on Windows.

Comment: Yes, this is where I had also got to after seeing both. I hoped I could move the old versions to a temporary directory and then rename them as the new without losing the history however it's gone. No more annoying little red icons though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error arose due to a conflict between the lowercase and uppercase files being recognised as two different files. This can be checked by running `git ls-tree -r HEAD --name-only`.

Because my last commit was only the name changes, I checked out the previous commit and used `git mv <old name> <new name>` to make sure that git knew the old file was being renamed and it wasn't a new file.

-- Edit --

The revision history now does not show when using just `git log <file>`, however adding the `--follow` tag, e.g. `git log --follow <file name>` as per TTT's suggestion shows the entire history as hoped for.

Comment: Believe it or not, Git doesn't actually track renames, and furthermore `git mv` doesn't really do anything differently than you did the first time, except maybe the first time around you only staged the add and forgot to stage the delete? `git mv` stages both the add and delete for you at the same time. Also, if you did what you said here then the revision history should follow through the rename without any issues (in most typical history views).

Comment: When I did the change I remember there being some weird business in that the first time, the files didn’t even flag as being different. Alas, when I’d made the changes using mv, looking at the git log for the files showed no commit history compared to before the change where they showed full history

Comment: Try `git log --follow`. I think some GUIs use that by default when viewing the history of a file.